# Regex to match the relative path of the URL

Tags: regex, url, relative-path

How to write the regex that all three situations below matches? The path, file, and query string has to be exact. The domain part could be any variants of the following (domain name/IP address)

```
http://www.example.com/path1/path2/foobar.aspx?id=123&key=456
https://www.example.com/path1/path2/foobar.aspx?id=123&key=456
64.123.456.789/path1/path2/foobar.aspx?id=123&key=456
```

Basically, only the **/path1/path2/foobar.aspx?id=123&key=456** needs to be matched. The part in front of it could be any of the variants lead user to the site.

Comment: will this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/PXyG2p/1/ or you need to validate that domain and ips are 'valid'?

Comment: Try with: [__`(?:\d|\w)+(\/.*)`__](https://regex101.com/r/xX7et6/1). But I think you better use an appropriate url parsing library. For example if you are trying to do this in python check out [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: why dont you try `^.+?\/path1\/path2\/foobar\.aspx\?id=123&key=456$`  or check at https://regex101.com/r/NAkemr/1

Comment: You could dig it out from [connection-string](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string), if you really want it. It parses the relative path there using RegEx, among other things ;) Or, you can just use the library, since it is tiny and works everywhere.

Comment: You cannot have things like `456` or `789` in an IPv4 address, 255 is the maximum.

Comment: @Julio thank you but your suggestion also matches even if I append more stuff after the URL

Comment: You may end the regex with `$` for that fix. Anyways, We should know if you need to validate the IP address and the domain names, or you can simply skip them. Also, does the id and key parameters must appear in that order?

Answer (score 1):

## Code

```
\.[^\/]+(.*)
```

[Try it online!](https://regexr.com/4qpgp)

This RegEx *captures* the relative path of the address. This means that you will need to get the match's capture in your used program rather than the matched characters.

---

### Explanation

```
\.              Gets the first dot of the address
  [^\/]+        Matches all characters that aren't forward slashes
        (.*)    Captures the rest of the address
```

---

**Further Explanation**

The reason why I'm not able to *match* (rather than *capture*) the address is because I don't have any expressions to definitely represent the beginning of the relative path (without having to match any other characters).

This is because some addresses have a protocol part (e.g.: `http://`) whereas others don't. The extra two forward slashes mean that the RegEx would become much lengthier in order to verify that we get to the correct forward slash.

I used the first dot since all addresses (as far as I know) have a dot in the domain (`www.something.com` or `64.123.456.789`). Since the domain is always immediately before the relative path, we can just skip to the next forward slash and always arrive at the relative path.

Then we just capture the rest of the address (including the first forward slash), which is then easy to get.

Comment: Even though the OP does not specifies a language or platform your example (and I mean the demo link) is only valid for Javascript RegEx parser, PRCE throws an error, and also does not answer the question since does not wrab the path from URL but almost everything else excluding schema and the www part from the domain.

Comment: @d70rr3s As far as I understand it, the request was to capture the relative path after the main address bit thing, so I didn't bother to try accomplish anything else; but it's very possible I misunderstand the question.

As for the code not working that is my fault for not escaping the forwards slash: `[^\/]+`

Comment: It does match the relative path using the group but full match includes part of the main address (strips the schema and the first .), so it cannot be use for replace functions directly it shoukd be addressed through callbacks. You should clarify your answer pointing that the first group (matches[1] or $1 in most parsers) is the proper group for replacement.