# How to use regex to extract the relative path of a url without path params or query params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

With NodeJS environment, how would you extract the relative path, while also not accounting for numeric path params, and all query params?

Say you have a url as a string: `https://localhost:8000/api/users/available/23342?name=john`

the goal is to get `api/users/available` from it. Below is an implementation, however, its highly ineffective and there has to be a better solution by doing it all via regex...

```
const url = 'https://localhost:8000/api/users/available/23342?name=john';

url
    .split("/")
    .splice("3")
    .join("/")
    .split("?")[0]
    .replace(/\/(\d*)$/, "");
};
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the point in doing this. Do tell.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043172/regex-to-match-the-relative-path-of-the-url/52047098

Comment: will the numeric params be always at the end of the relative path? Can there be more than one of those? Please add all relevant examples of valid and invalid ones in your question to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: `s.match(/(?:^|[^\/])\/(?!\/)((?:(?![^\/]*[?#])[^#?])+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single regex to replace the url. Here is the code with a bunch of urls to test:

```js
const urls = [
  'https://localhost:8000/api/users/available/23342?name=john',
  'https://example.com/api/users/available/23342?name=john',
  'https://example.com/api/users/available/23342',
  'https://example.com/api/users/available?name=john',
];
const regex = /^[a-z]+:\/\/[^:\/]+(:[0-9]+)?\/(.*?)(\/[0-9]+)?(\?.*)?$/;
urls.forEach((url) => {
  var result = url.replace(regex, '$2');
  console.log(url + ' ==> ' + result);
});
```

Output:

```
https://localhost:8000/api/users/available/23342?name=john ==> api/users/available
https://example.com/api/users/available/23342?name=john ==> api/users/available
https://example.com/api/users/available/23342 ==> api/users/available
https://example.com/api/users/available?name=john ==> api/users/available
```

Explanation of the regex search and replace:

- `^` ... `$` - anchor at start and end
- `[a-z]+:\/\/` - scan over protocol and `://`
- `[^:\/]+` - scan over domain name (anything before `:` or `/`
- `(:[0-9]+)?` - scan over port number (the `?` makes the preceding capture optional)
- `\/` - scan over `/` (first char of url path)
- `(.*?)` - non-greedily scan and capture over anything until:
- `(\/[0-9]+)?` - scan over a `/` and number chars, if any
- `(\?.*)?` - scan over query params, if any
- replace: `'$2'`, e.g. use the second capture only, which us the url path excluding number

Comment: BTW, since you stated node.js, you can simplify it by using the url package: `require('url').parse('https://localhost:8000/api/users/available/23342?name=john').pathname` will give you the url path, then use a simple regex `/^\/(.*?)(\/[0-9]+)?$/` with replace `'$1'` to get what you want.

Comment: @user10741122: Any questions on this answer? Does it fit your needs?